# Hibernate getting and saving a date with an extra day than the record on the database

Tags: java, hibernate, date, spring-mvc

Im having an issue when I fetch data from the DB with HIBERNATE and SpringMVC, everything works fine except for the dates. When I fetch a field of Date type, I receive the date but with a previous day.

For example, Im fetching the date as "**2022-08-28**", but im receiving "**2022-08-27**"

Also have an issue when I update the data, Hibernate saves on the next day that the date that is stored on the DB.

On the same example Im fetching the date as "**2022-08-28**", but when saving the record appears as  "**2022-08-29**"

This is my architechture

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente_tickets")
public class ClienteTicket {

    ... other fields...

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private Date updatedOn;

   ... other GettersAndSetters...

   public Date getCreatedOn() {
    return createdOn;
   }

   public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = createdOn;
   }

   public Date getUpdatedOn() {
    return updatedOn;
   }

   public void setUpdatedOn(Date updatedOn) {
    this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
   }

}
```

This is the method in my DAO

```
@Override
    public ClienteTicket buscarId(long id) {
        try {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ClienteTicket ct where ct.idTicket = :id", ClienteTicket.class)
                    .setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult(); 
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is the Service

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void guardar(ClienteTicket clienteTicket) {
        if (clienteTicket.getCreatedBy() == null || clienteTicket.getCreatedBy().length() == 0) {
            clienteTicket.setCreatedOn(new Date());
            clienteTicket.setCreatedBy(Utilidades.currentUser());
        } else {
            clienteTicket.setUpdatedOn(new Date());
            clienteTicket.setUpdatedBy(Utilidades.currentUser());
        }
        this.clienteTicketDao.guardar(clienteTicket);
    }
```

This is my controller for fetching the Object

```
@GetMapping("/editar")
    ModelAndView editar(@RequestParam("id") String id) throws ParseException {
        ClienteTicket ticket = this.ticketsService.buscarId(Long.parseLong(id));
        super.mv = new ModelAndView("/cliente/ticket_formulario");
        super.mv.addObject("clienteEncontrado", true);
        super.mv.addObject("editar", true);
        super.mv.addObject("clienteTicket", ticket);
        super.mv.addObject("idClienteActual", ticket.getCliente().getIdCliente());
        super.mv.addObject("estadosIncidencia", this.ticketEstadosService.listar());
        super.mv.addObject("tiposIncidencia", this.ticketTiposService.listar());
        super.mv.addObject("titulo", "Tickets");
        //this.ticketsService.guardar(ticket);
        return super.mv;
    }
```

When I Debug I get this [JAVA_DEBUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGBWB.png)

These are the properties of the DB [TABLE_PROPERTIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgJeT.png)

Current data on DB [DATA_TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwJYZ.png)

Date in JSP is hidden [DATA_JSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNfq3.png)

HTML [EDGE_DEVTOOLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJs3g.png)

Other data is fetched correctly [OTHER_DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1w1b.png)

Comment: what is your DB server Timezone? Compare with your pc's timezone

Comment: I've solved!, It was related with the Timezone.The timezone on my pc was right, the issue was the configuration on the jdbc.url. I was using serverTimezone=UTC, Im from Mexico so i needed to use CST. adding serverTimezone=CST to jdbc.url solved my issue. I hope this helps someone in the future. TY

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Here *local*  means without time zone, so this will automatically eliminate your time zone problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved!, It was related with the Timezone.The timezone on my pc was right, the issue was the configuration on the jdbc.url. I was using serverTimezone=UTC, Im from Mexico so i needed to use CST. adding serverTimezone=CST to jdbc.url solved my issue. I hope this helps someone in the future. TY

Change

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sge?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

To

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sge?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=CST&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```